# Best way to discover multiple merge bases in git

Tags: git

I have a bunch of branch and quickly want to determine how they are related to a specific branch `branchRef`. At the moment I invoke

```
git merge-base branchRef B
```

for each branch B from above bunch, but it's painfully slow because the repo contains two initial commits, i.e. some branches have no merge base with `branchRef` at all. To speed this up I'd like to know if there is some other command to use or if I'm missing some option to merge-base.

Alternatively, how would I enumerate all branches derived from branchRef? I could then form the intersection with all B and be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, any branch that has the same base commit as `branchRef` can be described as derived from `branchRef`

If that's ok as a definition, you can list these branches with :

```
git branch --contains <that base commit>
```